# Where is the internal DVD/CD-ROM drive with USB connector (not SATA)?

Tags: usb, sata, optical-drive

I wonder why internal optical drives are equipped with a SATA interface.
Why not USB 2.0 or 3.0 instead?

USB provides a transfer rate high enough and using USB to connect an optical drive would save a SATA port for another disk.

Why is this SATA port wasted for a comparably slow optical drive?
I am looking for an internal optical drive that is connected via USB.
Anyone knows?

@raw_noob made it pretty clear here at superuser:
[Will an external USB DVD writer perform the same like an internal SATA DVD Writer?](https://superuser.com/questions/123013/will-external-usb-dvd-writer-perform-same-like-internal-sata-dvd-writer)

Comment: Are you asking us to guess why no one has manufactured an internal USB optical drive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SATA is designed for internal use of External Memories ie HDD, ODD, SSD... to add some extra function like booting up device etc...

USB is designed for external use of those Memories.

As you can see, USB port is bigger and has less pin than SATA. You can easily break a SATA jack but not with a USB jack.

So by default all the External Memories are using SATA to transfer data, and the HDD box, external ODD just use the USB converter to make it external device.

Comment: @Nam_Phung Thank you. We never stop learning.